# How to check if a random mixed case word is in a string

Tags: python, string, lowercase, capitalization, mixed-case

I am trying to check to see if there is the word robot in a line. (I'm learning python. Still very new to it.) If the word 'robot' is in a line it prints something out. Same with 'ROBOT'. However, I need to know how to output when robot is in the line but in a randomly mixed case, eg rObOt. Is this possible? It seems like I would need to write out every combination. I'm using Python 3. Thanks :).

```
if ' robot ' in line:
  print("There is a small robot in the line.")
elif ' ROBOT ' in line:
  print("There is a big robot in the line.")
elif 'rOBOt' in line:
  print("There is a medium sized robot in the line.")
else:
  print("No robots here.")
```

Comment: Use `lower()` to convert the entire line to lowercase and then just check for `robot`. Finding out whether `robot` is a standalone word is a little bit harder, and is probably best solved using a regular expression with word boundaries.

Comment: `.lower()` both and compare then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the code below can help you.

```
line = "Hello robot RoBot ROBOT"

l = line.split(" ")

exist = False

for word in l:
    if word.upper() == "ROBOT":

        exist = True

        if word.isupper():
            print("There is a big robot in the line.")
        elif word.islower():
            print("There is a small robot in the line.")
        else:
            print("There is a medium sized robot in the line.")

if not exist:
    print("No robots here.")
```

Comment: Particularly as the OP has stated that they are new to Python, your answer would benefit from a little explanation. Also, why the use of `exist` rather than simple `else`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lower()` which is a string method to convert a string to lowercase in Python.

So the idea is after you check for small case and capital case, if there is a robot in arbitrary case, it will be picked up in the third condition.

```
if ' robot ' in line:
  print("There is a small robot in the line.")
elif ' ROBOT ' in line:
  print("There is a big robot in the line.")
elif ' robot ' in line.lower():
  print("There is a medium sized robot in the line.")
else:
  print("No robots here.")
```

Also, I notice that you place a space before and after the word `robot`, I am guessing you would like to place a space for the third condition as well.

Comment: What if the robot is at the end of the line? `Doomo arigatoo Mr. Robot!`

Comment: Good question. I think that depends on what does he wants to check. Regular expression could be a good tool as well.